# Error: Cannot find name ‘MoreInfo’ while trying to push to MoreinfoPage from HomePage

Tags: ionic2

I'm trying to load MoreinfoPage from HomePage upon button click, I get the following error:

> Typescript Error Cannot find name 'MoreinfoPage'.

**home.html**

```
<button [navPush]="moreinfoPage">More Info</button>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MoreinfoPage } from 'pages/moreinfo/moreinfo'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  moreinfoPage: MoreinfoPage;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){}
}
```

I haven't made any changes to the default folder structure. Why can't it find the MoreinfoPage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The type should be set to any and the page needs to be assigned to the variable.

```
moreinfoPage: any = MoreinfoPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [NavPush](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavPush/).

You need to set page in constructor.

```
export class HomePage {
  moreinfoPage: MoreinfoPage;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){
    this.moreinfoPage = MoreinfoPage;//here
}
}
```